# How to align dropdown list and img button?

Tags: html, css

Hi i have following (View)html code and css produced this result, how do i align it?

Result

[image]

View

```
<div class="divfloatleft" >@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tintFactorType , slFactorType, new { @class = "divfloatleft rulestextbox5" })</div>
<div class="divfloatleft" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.decFactorValue, new { @class = "divfloatleft rulestextbox6" })</div>
<div class="divfloatleft" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.decMaxBonus, new { @class = "divfloatleft rulestextbox7" })</div>
<div class="divfloatleft" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nvarMsg , new { @class = "divfloatleft rulestextbox8" })</div>
<div class="divfloatleft" >@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.varVCode  , new { @class = "divfloatleft rulestextbox9" })</div>
<div  onclick="removeControl(this);return false;" class="remove removeimg divfloatleft"></div>
```

css

```
.rulestextbox5 {
    min-width: 125px !important;  
    width:125px !important;  
    height:30px !important;  
    margin-right:6px;
    top:30px;
}


.rulestextbox6 {
    min-width: 80px !important;  
    width:80px !important;  
    height:20px !important;  
    margin-right:6px;
}


.rulestextbox7 {
    min-width: 89px !important;  
    width:89px !important;  
    height:20px !important;  
    margin-right:6px;
}


.rulestextbox8 {
    min-width: 72px !important;  
    width:72px !important;  
    height:20px !important;  
    margin-right:6px;
}


.rulestextbox9 {
    min-width: 70px !important;  
    width:70px !important;  
    height:20px !important;  
    margin-right:6px;
}

.removeimg { 
     cursor:pointer;
    width: 19px !important;    
    height: 18px !important;  
    background: transparent url("images/basicsetup/remove.png") no-repeat center center !important; 
}
```

Comment: have you tried top: 34px; for .rulestextbox5? And as well there is no reason to set width and min-width together, as min-width is not taken into account in such situation

Comment: Yes, i tried a number bigger than 34px as well, it's still same. If  not set the min-width it will override by the jquery's min-width. So i have to do this but not sure is the right way to do this.

Comment: You can try by reading the whole style applied to your divs and combobox (I like to use Google Chrome's dev tools), if you see here: http://jsfiddle.net/eKwyk/ you cannot see that behavior, and if you do something like position: relative; top: 0px; then you can force it to align based on the top.

Comment: @porfiriopartida thanks.! I'm not sure why mine behave so, may be because of the above html surrounded by fieldset? and i try position:relation, it's works.! I like to accept your answer but you put in comment, :).

Comment: There is the answer :p . Also try to provide fiddle.. it is easier for everybody to read and get what you need since it is "a reproduced issue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to check with a dev tool the css that may be affecting your combobox and div besides the CSS you showed us.

```
position: relative;
top: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea to put all of them in a table with 5 columns and 1 row.
No need to use a seperate div for each component unless you need it. I put one component as an example the rest should be done the same way.

```
   <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.tintFactorType , slFactorType, new { @class = "divfloatleft rulestextbox5" })
         </td>
       </tr>
   </table>
```

If you need to use class or ID just add it to them using span tag, since you need to make them disappear.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, it's because of the dynamically add the above html during run-time. and also i tried your approach before not sure why it's not shown so i switch it to div instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just add display:block for .divfloatleft

CSS:

```
.divfloatleft {
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
}
```